# Easiest way to run Java program in the Cloud?

Tags: java, cloud

I'm working on a small side-project for our company that does the following:

- PDF-based documents received through Office 365 Outlook are temporarily stored in OneDrive, using Power Automate
- Text data is extracted from the PDFs using a few Java libraries
- Based on extracted data an appropriate filename and filepath is created
- The PDFs are permanently saved in OneDrive

The issue right now is that my Java program is locally-run, i.e. point 2,3,4 require code to run 24/7 on my PC. I'd like to transition to a Cloud-based solution.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? The solution doesn't have to be free, but shouldn't cost more than $20/mo. Our company already has an Azure subscription, though I'm not familiar yet with Azure.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a solution that uses a [serverless computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing) execution model. [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) seems to be a possible choice here. It does seem to have [input bindings that respond to OneDrive files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph#onedrive-input) and an likewise [output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph#file-output).

The cost will depend on the number of documents, not the time the solution is available. I assume we are talking about a small number of documents a month so this will come out cheaper than other execution models.

Comment: The solution would have to process a few thousand documents per month.

Comment: Chances are that a server would process a few thousand documents in a day, so we are talking about a dedicated cloud instance being mostly idle. My bet would be that the serverless computing solution would be significantly cheaper. If you have a rough measure for how long each document takes then you can estimate it.

Comment: Locally it takes me around 5 seconds to process a document, so times 5000 documents/month would be about 7hrs/month the application needs to run. After looking into Azure Functions it seems that going Serverless definitely would make the most sense.